# How to get segment of uri after translation?

Tags: php, regex

How to get from uri for example:  `/en/joe-doe/contact`  to  `joe-doe/contact` ?  The language is dynamic and can change.

Uri:  `/en/joe-doe/contact/form`

Wanted uri : `joe-doe/contact/form`

Comment: Why you need regex if string is fixed. Just use substring method and get it.

Comment: If you know the language code - you could just return the segment after `/code/`.

Comment: the problem is i need to get right url and then trim it in code to get proper segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Just use `str_replace` and remove the `/en/` from the string.

PHP Code,

```
$s = "/en/joe-doe/contact";
echo str_replace('/en/', '', $s);
```

Output,

```
joe-doe/contact
```

But if the string in start is dynamic, then you can use this regex,

```
^/[^/]*/
```

And replace it with empty string.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVjJPc/1)**

PHP codes,

```
$s = "/somedynamic string/joe-doe/contact";
echo preg_replace('~/[^/]*/~', '', $s);
```

Prints,

```
joe-doe/contact
```

Comment: Added regex solution too if your string in start is dynamic.

Comment: with last one the problem is this :  **/en/dfsdafasdfa-dsfa/dsfafasd-sdfas/232314**   -> **dfsdafasdfa-dsfa232314**   i  lost other  / after segment 0

Comment: What's your expected string out of this `/it/dfsdafasdfa-dsfa/dsfafasd-sdfas/232314` ? Is this `dfsdafasdfa-dsfa232314` ? Can you please add these and better more strings in your post and expected output?

Comment: This:  dfsdafasdfa-dsfa/dsfafasd-sdfas/232314

Comment: @Neo: You get that with the regex solution I've added in my answer. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/JVjJPc/2)